# QT quit does not call MainWindow destructor

Tags: c++, qt

In my application I have a tray icon and so I overrode closeEvent so that the application "minimizes" when certain things happen. However, I do expect that upon pressing exit, that the application will completely exit. However, after overriding closeEvent and calling the function quit(), it seems to bypass the MainWindow destructor, where I have some code.
What am I missing in closeEvent to properly close the application so that the destructor of MainWindow is called, as is the case when closeEvent isn't overriden?

I've tried using

```
 QMainWindow::closeEvent(event);
```

and a few other things, but the destructor is never called.

My close event implementation is:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent * event)
{
    if(m_closeCompletely == false)
    {
        if (trayIcon->isVisible())
        {
            QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Hello"),
                                     tr("The program will keep running in the "
                                        "system tray. To terminate the program, "
                                        "choose <b>Quit</b> in the context menu "
                                        "of the system tray entry."));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        event->accept();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some more context? How did you implement `closeEvent()`? Did you try the sample from the documentation? http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent

Answer (score 4):

The WA_DeleteOnClose attribute needs to be set to call the destructor on a close event, otherwise a widget or window is just hidden from view. Add the following to the class constructor:

```
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

This will cause the destructor to be called on a close event.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on where and how you allocated the objects you are using. If you create the `QApplication` and `QMainWindow` on the heap then they will lurk around until the OS cleans up the memory. Sending a `close()` to a `QWidget` (and `QMainWindow` is one) will only `close` it .. hide it visually from the user. You can `show()` later on, `close()` does not destruct it.

You could use something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   MyMainWindow mw;
   mw.show();

   int rc = app.exec();

   // optional: do_cleanup();

   return rc;
}
```

`app` and `mw` are constructed on the stack. They will be destructed in reverse order when the `app` returns from the `exec()` call (usually when you send `quit()` to the `QCoreApplication::instance()`). You can even provide a plain cleanup function, no need to put something into the destructor of the UI.

Comment: They are both constructed at the struct. Perhaps I should take your suggestion and avoid using deconstructor.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that all the **Application Resources** are hold by the `QApplication`;

Once your `MainWindow` is closed, it just be `close`, aka hide from the screen;

I wonder why you want to destructor your `MainWindow`, it seems that you've made a system tray entry, so my suggestion is just to **hide** the `MainWindow` but to **destructor**, cause there is a system tray, you may want to click it to show the `MainWindow`.

Hope to Help. : )

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem and it was because I was running an infinite loop that never allowed the application to close.

```
forever
{
    _runGameLoop();
}
```

I had to make the loop end when `MainWindow` closed

```
while(!M->isClosed())
{
    _runGameLoop();
}
```

And of course I had to implement `isClosed()`

```
bool MainWindow::isClosed()
{
    return _isClosed;
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent*)
{
    _isClosed = true;
}
```